# Version number annotation for private repositories with NPM

Tags: node.js, git, npm, bitbucket

I’m pulling a tool that I’m working on into one of our projects at work. The tool is in a private bitbucket repository and I’m pulling it into the project with the following dependency line in the project’s package.json:

```
"content-deployment-tool": "git+https://<account>:<apikey>@bitbucket.org/<account>/content-deployment-tool.git#2.0.2",
```

This works, but it’s a PITA b/c I’m having to increment the tag number each time I update and push a new tag in the content-deployment-tool repository.

I’ve tried out using the semantic versioning wild cards to note the version number I want like `…#^2.0.0`, but I get an error when trying.

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/bin/git checkout ^2.0.0
npm ERR! error: pathspec '^2.0.0' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Do I need to hard code it every time? I’m having trouble finding documentation on noting version numbers from private repos specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dev in one of my slack teams pointed me to the right syntax. I'm posting this here so that people who are stuck on the same issue have the answer and I'll give him the check if he posts an answer later.

> It’s in NPM 5. https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v5.0.0

If you look under the "Installer changes" section of the release notes you'll see the correct syntax for specifying semantic version number notation with a git repository.

> Git dependencies now support semver-based matching: npm install git://github.com/npm/npm#semver:^5 (#15308, #15666)

I updated my package.json dependency to:

```
"content-deployment-tool": "git+https://<account>:<apikey>@bitbucket.org/<account>/content-deployment-tool.git#semver:^2.0.0",
```

And now my updates are pulling correctly without having to manually update the tag number in my target project's package.json.